# jQuery plugin not firing

Tags: jquery

Good Day,

I have a form with two textboxes and have used the following code on other pages so I know this works.

```
$(document).on('focusout', '.rate', function() {
    var thisTextbox = $(this).val();

    if (thisTextbox.length > 0) {
        var number = parseFloat(thisTextbox);
        if (!isNaN(number))
            $(this).val(String.format("{0:#,0.00}", number));
    }
});
```

This will format the number (i.e. 45 => 45.00, 1324 => 1,324.00).  It uses an external String.format javascript library.  For those interested, I found the library here:  http://www.masterdata.se/r/string_format_for_javascript/.  The link to download is at the upper left corner.

I am now going to be using this code in multiple places and would like to create a plugin that I can invoke like:

```
$(".rate").setDollarAmount();
```

My plugin looks like:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.setDollarAmount = function(options) {

    var classActivator = 'rate';

    return this.each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(classActivator)) {
            $(document).on('focusout', classActivator, function() {
                var thisTextbox = $(this).val();

                if (thisTextbox.length > 0) {
                    var number = parseFloat(thisTextbox);
                    if (!isNaN(number))
                        $(this).val(String.format("{0:#,0.00}", number));
                }
            });             
        }
    });
};
```

}( jQuery ));

The code is running when I load the page as I can step through it.  But when I move from one textbox to the next, the event doesn't fire off.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form>
<input name="one" class="financial" />
<br />
<input name="two" />
</form>

<a href="http://www.nbcnews.com">My Link</a>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/stringformat-1.09.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.greenify.js"></script>
<script src="js/dollarAmount.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {

    $("input[name=one]").setDollarAmount();

    $('div').greenify({
        text: 'Hola',
        color: '#FF0000'
    });
});

</script>
```

Is there anything I else I need to do to get this to work?

TIA,

coson

Comment: Why are you binding to document inside that?? Just bind to the element.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because your plugin is in a function, and this enclosing function runs only once (when you load the page)

Instead of:

```
(function($) { [...] }( jQuery ));
```

try adding this at the beginning of the file:

```
var $ = (undefined === $) ? jQuery : $;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following epascarello's comment, I reworked the plugin to:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.setDollarAmount = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).on('focusout', function() {
                var thisTextbox = $(this).val();

                if (thisTextbox.length > 0) {
                    var number = parseFloat(thisTextbox);
                    if (!isNaN(number))
                        $(this).val(String.format("{0:#,0.00}", number));
                }
            });     
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

and life is good.  Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong.

1. The input elements your calling your plugin on don't have a `rate` class. You check if they have this class before binding the event, and you only bind to elements with this class, even though none exist in your html.
2. You don't have a dot infront of your selector in the event. It should be `'.' + classActivator`

Those two changes work, if you try this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xz7ob8tj/

But even then, I wouldn't write it like that. For one, your `each()` call just binds the same event to the same class multiple times. It just needs to be binded once to a class.  Additionally, your `hasClass` is redundant, because events binded to a class won't be called on elements that don't have that class. You could do this without a plugin, simply:

```
var classActivator = "rate";
$(document).on('focusout', "." + classActivator, function() {
    var thisTextbox = $(this).val();

    if (thisTextbox.length > 0) {
        var number = parseFloat(thisTextbox);
        if (!isNaN(number))
         $(this).val(String.format("{0:#,0.00}", number));
    }
});
```

Or with a plugin that doesn't use a class, it just binds to the elements in the selection that it's called on:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.setDollarAmount = function(options) {
        this.focusout(function(){
            var thisTextbox = $(this).val();

            if (thisTextbox.length > 0) {
                var number = parseFloat(thisTextbox);
                if (!isNaN(number))
                 $(this).val(String.format("{0:#,0.00}", number));
            }
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

But a plugin doesn't seem necessary for this imho.